# Check Android soft keyboard visibility

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, keyboard, uitextfield, android-softkeyboard

I work on editing code of [UnityNativeEdit](https://github.com/YousicianGit/UnityNativeEdit) that is about text field by native keyboard in **Unity3D** which is handled by native android plugin.

I want that soft keyboard doesn't cover text field. So by searching find the solution by placing this piece of code in `OnCreate` method:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

And It looks like this:

[image]

As you see keyboard cover a little part of text field background. Actually I want margin or padding between keyboard and text field. I've search many times but none of solutions solve my problem.

After that I've tried to solve this problem in **Unity3D** by scrolling panel up and down, So I need to find out soft keyboard is visible or not, because keyboard is handled in native plugin so I can't use `TouchScreenKeyboard.visible`, then I've searched about keyboard visibility in android, I found a solution but this solution just works by setting softInputMode as `SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE` and by setting that we have scrolling in background for showing text field.

Do you have any solution for solving this problem ?

Comment: Is there any layout associated with the activity? If yes, can you please post the layout too?

Comment: Can you explain more about your question, because I don't have much experience with Android. If you mean XML file, I've not set anything for UI elements.

Comment: Any solution for keyboard visibility ?

Comment: @ZayedUpal can you please look into this question?

Comment: Anyone ? Any solution ? Any advice ?

Comment: Any solution for finding out if soft keyboard is visible or not without set softInputMode  to `SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE` ?